# What .NET framework should I use for a CMS/social network hybrid?

Tags: c#, cms, .net, framework, asp.net

I am going to be starting a project in .NET/C# and am looking for the right framework to use.

The general idea for the project is that there will be an administrative back end similar to a CMS. But instead of presenting just content like a blog or whatever it will manage a social community. This social community will be build so that it is made of parts like widgets that users can put together in this admin area.

So, I am looking for advice about where to start. I want to do .NET MVC and probably use Angular. Other than that I am not sure where to go.

When looking for CMS frameworks I see:

- **DotNetNuke**. Its site says it's scalable, future proof and easy to use. That's good, but vague.
- **Umbraco**, which can also scale, easy to integrate, and simple to use. Ok, great!
- Then there is **MonoX**, which looks just like what I want, but it costs money and is newer, so is it really better?